# isql wait for end of query on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql-server-2008, progress, isql

i'm using isql sdk to make Microsoft Sql 2008 query through iphone, everything works fine but I always need to click two button to get the answer of my query. I press the button 'submit' then i can press the button 'next page' and the result will show on the next page but if i put my query in the next page button, the app switch to the next page but since the query isn't finished my text view is empty, so is there a way to make the app wait for the end of a query, it would be great if the entire app could pause and an activity indicator shows up until the query finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my app wait for the query to finish I use something like SVProgressHUD
https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD

Basically when I execute the query I display the hud (which halts user interaction)

Then when the query finishes I deal with the data returned (change views, update textfields, etc.) then dismiss the HUD.

Comment: Yeah i did the same but with MBProgressHUD and i forgot to post it.